# Unexpected behavior with word find and replace for `?{1,2}`. Matching long strings of characters

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, find, find-and-replace, wildcards

Question relates to word's find and replace with wildcards enabled (quasi regex).

According to [this microsoft page](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7?CorrelationId=9fa471fd-2ddc-46df-a874-c965fa66b312&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB):

- ? represents any single character (like . in regex)
- {n,m} represents a defined number of characters between n and m.

However, I'm getting the following results

source string: *aaaaaaaabbbbbbbaaaaa*

> find what: `b{1,2}a`
>   
> result: abbbbb**bba**aaaa
>   
> *(expected)*

> find what: `??a`
>   
> result: abbbbb**bba**aaaa
>   
> *(expected)*

> find what: `?{1,2}a`
>   
> result: **abbbbbbba**aaaa

What on earth is happening with the last one??  It seems to be behaving like *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the webpage you provided:

> {n,m} - From n to m occurrences of the previous **character** or **expression**

and

> () - **Expression**

and

> ? - **Any single character**, including space and punctuation characters

So I think "?" is not treated as "character" in this case (as "?" is "any single character"), but when you surround it with parenthesis it becomes expression and it works.

So the correct regex here is: (?){1,2}a

Comment: This isn't clear at all in the documentation, thank you for helping me figure this out!